# Iterate a treemap from specific key to end of map

Tags: java, collections, treemap

```
    TreeMap treemap=new TreeMap<String,double>();
    treemap.put("02.00", 7.5);
    treemap.put("03.30", 7.9);
    treemap.put("04.00", 8.0);
    treemap.put("05.30", 6.8);
    treemap.put("10.00", 9.01);
    treemap.put("11.30", 8.9);
    treemap.put("12.00", 9.30);
    System.out.println(treemap);
    double min=(double) Collections.min(treemap.values());
```

> Treemap contains --  {02.00=7.5, 03.30=7.9, 04.00=8.0, 05.30=6.8,
>   10.00=9.01, 11.30=8.9, 12.00=9.30} min contains value : 6.8

Now i want to iterate key and value after

```
 treemap.put("05.30", 6.8);
```

i.e.,

```
  treemap.put("10.00", 9.01);
  treemap.put("11.30", 8.9);
  treemap.put("12.00", 9.30);
```

and store last three map key and value in another treemap..

Comment: do you want to iterate over the last elements of collection after the element that has the least value in the collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TreeMap` has a method `tailMap(K fromKey)` which returns a `SortedMap<K, V>` whose keys are greater than / equal to K.

Comment: If you read all the message you've seen that the value to test is not a "key" but a a "value" so it doesn't work

Comment: I don't think I misinterpreted the title of that question but feel free to provide an alternate solution if you think otherwise.